# ImageMagick-7.0.1-3.x86_64.rpm installation on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7

Tags: imagemagick

Trying to install ImageMagick 7.0.1-3 on Redhat 6.7 :

```
$sudo rpm -ivh ImageMagick-7.0.1-3.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        ImageMagick-libs = 7.0.1-3 is needed by ImageMagick-7.0.1-3.x86_64
        libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.0()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-7.0.1-3.x86_64
        libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.0()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-7.0.1-3.x86_64
        libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.0(VERS_1.0)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-7.0.1-3.x86_64
        liblzma.so.5()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-7.0.1-3.x86_64
```

i was able to install ImageMagick using the tar.gz distribution for the same release.

Now since i would like to have a binary, so i can install it on production servers, but when trying to create an rpm , i get:

rpmbuild -ba ImageMagick.spec
error: Failed build dependencies:
        jbigkit-devel is needed by ImageMagick-7.0.1-3.x86_64

Where to get jbgkit-devel ?? and the rest of the dependencies ? 
Is there an alternate way to install ImageMagick ?

[jbigkit](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/jbigkit/) does not mention jbigkit-devel

Also, using the ImageMagick.spec provided in the tar.gz distribution i tried to make an rpm, but i get error:

```
# rpmbuild -ba ImageMagick.spec
error: Failed build dependencies:
        jbigkit-devel is needed by ImageMagick-7.0.1-3.x86_64
```

Which is back to square one, i tried to copy jbigkit-2.1.tar.gz in SOURCES, but i get the same error for jbigkit-devel is needed

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [the ImageMagick binary releases](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php),

the second link is the `libs`. Do that first and then the first link.
It worked for me and I got here looking to solve the error you entered.